# When using templates, how do I fix the following compiler error to achieve the desired behavior of my program?

Tags: c++, debugging, templates, c++11, compiler-errors

I'm practicing templates in *Visual Studio 2013* from a not so well written C++ book and I receive the following compiler errors respectively, **"error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int"** and **"error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '<'"**.

Both refer me to line 10 which is...

`std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const Array<T>&);`

The *desired behavior* of my code is to show the creation and destruction of temporary Animal objects using templates.

The *troubleshooting steps* I have tried so far include substituting **std::iostream&** with **int** in my return type and first parameter type of line 10. After doing so the error messages remained the same. This seemed to suggest that the problem may be the second parameter type. I then added the keyword **typename** to the second parameter of my overloading operator function (operator<<) on line 10 and the error still persisted.

Line 10 can be found in the header file below.

### //Array.h

> ```
> #ifndef ARRAY_H
> #define ARRAY_H
>
> #include <iostream>
> #include "Animal.h"
>
> const int DefaultSize = 3;
>
> template <typename T>
> std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const Array<T>&);
>
> template <typename T> // declare the template and the paramenter
> class Array               // the class being parameterized
> {
> public:
>   Array(int itsSize = DefaultSize);
>   Array(const Array &rhs);
>   ~Array() { delete[] pType; }
>
>   // operators
>   Array& operator=(const Array&);
>   T& operator[](int offSet) { return pType[offSet]; }
>   const T& operator[](int offSet) const { return pType[offSet]; }
>
>   // accessors
>   int GetSize() const { return itsSize; }
>
>   // friend function
>   friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const Array<T>&);
>
> private:
>   T *pType;
>   int itsSize;
> };
>
> template <typename T>
> Array<T>::Array(int size = DefaultSize) :itsSize(size)
> {
>   pType = new T[size];
>   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
>       pType[i] = static_cast<T>(0);
> }
>
> Array<Animal>::Array(int AnimalArraySize) :itsSize(AnimalArraySize)
> {
>   pType = new Animal[AnimalArraySize];
> }
>
> template <typename T>
> Array<T>::Array(const Array &rhs)
> {
>   itsSize = rhs.GetSzie();
>   pType = new T[itsSize];
>   for (int i = 0; i < itsSize; i++)
>       pType[i] = rhs[i];
> }
>
> template <typename T>
> Array<T>& Array<T>::operator=(const Array &rhs)
> {
>   if (this == &rhs)
>       return *this;
>   delete[] pType;
>   itsSize = rhs.GetSize();
>   pType = new T[itsSize];
>   for (int i = 0; i < itsSize; i++)
>       pType[i] = rhs[i];
>   return *this;
> }
>
> template <typename T>
> std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& output, const Array<T> &theArray)
> {
>   for (int i = 0; i < theArray.GetSize(); i++)
>       output << "[" << i << "]" << theArray[i] << std::endl;
>   return output;
> }
>
> #endif
> ```

Here's the rest of my code from my book for your reference.

### //Animal.h

> ```
> #ifndef ANIMAL_H
> #define ANIMAL_H
>
> #include <iostream>
>
> class Animal
> {
> public:
>   // constructors
>   Animal();
>   Animal(int);
>   ~Animal();
>
>   // accessors
>   int GetWeight() const { return itsWeight; }
>   void SetWeight(int theWeight) { itsWeight = theWeight; }
>
>   // friend operators
>   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Animal&);
>
> private:
>   int itsWeight;
> };
>
> #endif
> ```

### //Animal.cpp

> ```
> #include "Animal.h"
> #include <iostream>
>
> Animal::Animal() :itsWeight(0)
> {
>   std::cout << "animal() ";
> }
>
> Animal::Animal(int weight) : itsWeight(weight)
> {
>   std::cout << "animal(int) ";
> }
>
> Animal::~Animal()
> {
>   std::cout << "Destroyed an animal...";
> }
> ```

### //Main.cpp

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include "Animal.h"
> #include "Array.h"
>
> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Animal&);
> void IntFillFunction(Array<int>& theArray);
> void AnimalFillFunction(Array<Animal>& theArray);
>
> int main()
> {
>   Array<int> intArray;
>   Array<Animal> animalArray;
>   IntFillFunction(intArray);
>   AnimalFillFunction(animalArray);
>   std::cout << "intArray...\n" << intArray;
>   std::cout << "\nanimalArray...\n" << animalArray << std::endl;
>
>   std::cin.get();
>
>   return 0;
> }
>
> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& theStream, const Animal& theAnimal)
> {
>   theStream << theAnimal.GetWeight();
>   return theStream;
> }
>
> void IntFillFunction(Array<int>& theArray)
> {
>   bool Stop = false;
>   int offset, value;
>   while (!Stop)
>   {
>       std::cout << "Enter an offset (0-9) and a value. ";
>       std::cout << "(-1 to stop): ";
>       std::cin >> offset >> value;
>       if (offset < 0)
>           break;
>       if (offset > 9)
>       {
>           std::cout << "***Please use values between 0 and 9.***\n";
>           continue;
>       }
>       theArray[offset] = value;
>   }
> }
>
> void AnimalFillFunction(Array<Animal>& theArray)
> {
>   Animal *pAnimal;
>   for (int i = 0; i < theArray.GetSize(); i++)
>   {
>       pAnimal = new Animal(i * 10);
>       theArray[i] = *pAnimal;
>       delete pAnimal;
>   }
> }
> ```

*I've tried my best to keep this question on topic by providing you with the desired behavior of the program, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it. All of which are requirements for debugging help as documented in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page.
I'm new to this website, and if my question is still off-topic, please let me know how I can change my question to be more on topic or inform me of a better place to ask my question. - Thank you*

Comment: Why is the `operator<<` declared before the `Array` class and as a friend within the `Array` class?

Comment: This is how the code was written in the book. The only changes I made was separating them into different files. I made sure to include the implementation of my template functions in the template header Array.h. I was having some difficulties with a linker error and I found a page on stack overflow that suggested I create a function prototype for my friend function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is declared before the `Array` class is declared (i.e., the compiler has never seen that type and doesn't know what it is, hence your error).

```
template<typename> class Array; // Add this forward declaration

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const Array<T>&);
```

### Edit

I just noticed that the `operator<<` is declared before the `Array` class and as a friend function within the `Array` class. You could just remove the declaration at the top.

### Edit 2

#### Array.h

I removed the following items

```
#include "Animal.h"

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const Array<T>&);

Array<Animal>::Array(int AnimalArraySize) :itsSize(AnimalArraySize)
{
  pType = new Animal[AnimalArraySize];
}
```

Updated the friend function declartion to be

```
template<typename T> // This is not a member function so must be declared as a template
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const Array<T>&);
```

#### Animal.h

This class has the friend function but it's not implemented in the cpp file. I moved the definition from the main.cpp into Animal.cpp

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions and by the way the forward declaration makes complete sense to me and does indeed remove the compiler error as well as removing the function prototype which is line 10. However, by adding the forward declaration or removing line 10 altogether, I receive the same linker error which is the following.

Comment: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class Array<class Animal> const &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@ABV?$Array@VAnimal@@@@@Z) referenced in function _main

Comment: As you can see, template errors are very difficult to read and understand. Is this linker error related to my friend function or is it an entirely unrelated error?

Comment: @WanderingIdiot I compiled your code with a few more changes see _Edit 2_.

Comment: Thank you for finding this little problem but a big thorn in my side. Being a friend function it isn't part of the class itself and since the friend function contains a template parameter it needs to be declared as a template. I'm not sure why you decided to remove the specialized template function as it still ran fine with it. Again this is from the book and a very poorly written book it is. I'm more confident using templates now. Thank you for catching the nastiness which is templates with friend functions with template parameters and I now consider this topic closed.